# I'm getting a wrong postKey from push(), when I'm trying to get the key when I'm uploading the post

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When uploading the post, I'm trying to get the postKey and upload it to dynamiclink, but I'm getting wrong postKey (first 6 characters in the key are right then the rest are wrong). How can I get the right postKey when uploading the post?

This is my post including the right postKey:

[image: post image]

And this is what I'm getting **-LYelE9TdCU73qW1Xisc** , which also is not a key for any other posts.

My code

```
String postKey = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts").push().getKey();
        Log.i("postkey for dynamiclink",postKey);
```

Very much appreciated your help!

Comment: Thanks Peter, you are right I was creating another postkey. I removed the duplicated  .push() and using my same line of code it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are creating another `postKey` by using `push().getKey()`.

To retrieve the key, that is already in the database, try the following:

```
  DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("posts");

reference.orderByChild("title").equalTo("test").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
     String keys=datas.getKey();
    }
 }
@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, you are right I was creating another postkey. I removed the duplicated  .push() and using my same line of code it solved the problem.